# How to Define array values in YAML and fetch the keys - Mule 4

Tags: yaml, mule, dataweave, mule4

I'm trying to define the array in Mule YAML configuration to dynamically retrieve the `key` based on the value.

For example, I have a  flow variable  `code= finance`. Use code to loop through the list to fetch the key `roles` (below example). likewise, if the variable has 'emp1' should fetch the key `employee`.

Edited questions to give more clarity.

YAML configuration:

```
list:
  roles:
    - admin
    - finance
    - hr
    - sales
  employee:
    - emp1
    - emp2
    - emp3
```

Tried redefining the YAML file as described on this Page https://www.w3schools.io/file/yaml-multiline-arrays/ as below (see the `---` to distinguish this as a list in YAML so that I can use `(p('list')` in dw to loop through. Mule did not like it either.

```
list:
---
  roles:
    - admin
    - finance
    - hr
    - sales
  employee:
    - emp1
    - emp2
    - emp3
```

Mule not liking it or how to define multi-line array and fetch the key dynamically?
Any advice and thoughts?

Please let me know if the question is not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to find the key in the input YAML for a given value. You can use the function findKeyForValue() below. It transverse the objects and arrays to find the value, then return the key to which value belongs. It may require changes for more complex structures.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
import * from dw::core::Arrays
fun findKeyForValue(x, v) = do {
    fun findKeyInternal(x,v,lastKeyName) =
        x match {
            case o is Object -> namesOf(o) flatMap findKeyInternal(o[$], v, $) filter $ != null
            case a is Array -> if (a some ($ == v)) lastKeyName else null
            else -> $
        }
    var result=findKeyInternal(x, v, "")
    ---
    if (sizeOf(result)>0) result[0] else null

}
---
findKeyForValue(vars.code, "emp2")
```

Output for the input in the question:

```json
"employee"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [splitBy function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-splitby) splits a given string based on a value that matches part of that string.

If you change your DataWeave expression to:

```
%dw 2.0
output json
---
p('list.roles')
```

the output will be and array of strings:

```
[
  "admin",
  "finance",
  "hr",
  "sales"
]
```

So, what your DataWeave expression is trying to do is to apply the splitBy function over an array, which won't work.

In order to make your DataWeave expression work, you need to apply the filter directly, like in the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/java
---
p('list.roles') filter $ == vars.code
```

This will return an array of strings containing none or one item, depending on the vars.code value. In order to return null or the role, you can use the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
((p('list.roles') default []) filter $ == vars.code)[0]
```

This is for the technical part.

It seems that what you are trying to achieve is to check if the role contained in vars.code exists in the input payload (if vars.code value exists in list.roles, the DataWeave expression will return the exact same vars.code value). If that's the case, the DataWeave expression could be adjusted to return a boolean value telling if the role exists in the role list. You can achieve this using the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
isEmpty((p('list.roles') default []) filter $ == vars.code)
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. Sorry if my question confused you. Basically when a variable has `finance` expression should extract 'roles' and if the variable is `emp1` should extract `employee`. Is there anyway expression to go through the list of `p('list)` and fetch the `key` dynamically based on the variable being set.